# asp.net mvc : disable mvc form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an application in which an user can edit a form. This is my code :

Controller and ViewModel :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MyGlobalObject MyGlobalObject)
    {
        MyGlobalObject.Save();
        return View();
    }
}

public class MyGlobalObject
{
    public MyObjectToEdit MyObjectToEdit { get; set; }        
}

public  class MyObjectToEdit
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }

    public bool MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

My razor view :

@model TestAppliWeb.Controllers.MyGlobalObject

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "HomeController"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyObjectToEdit)
}
```

Everything is working well. But I would like to bring a new feature to this form, depending a certain condition, itself depending of MyProperty2 of MyObjectToEdit, I would like to continue to display the form but disabled it : all the form must be displayed to the user but he cannot edit anything and click on save.

If MyProperty2 is true, the form continue to be editable, if not, the form must be disabled. But I don't know how to impact it with a minimal of code in my razor view the rendering of the form. I have a solution, but it seems too "unclean" : I disabled all the elements of the form with javascript and css.

Is there any mvc html helper or anything like this to write in the razor view to disable the form.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: it seems something to be solve using angular

Comment: A disabled form is pointless, and you should be displaying a different view with simple text only from the controller based on the condition

Comment: _I disabled all the elements of the form with javascript and css_ What's wrong with that? `$(".myform-item").prop("disabled", true)`. But really, just don't display a form until an edit is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I typically use jQuery to disable and enable input fields.

**Disable:**

```
$('#idVar').prop("disabled", true);
```

**Enable:**

```
$('#idVar').prop("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is something like the following:

**Create a helper to hold all of the form content**

```
@helper FormContent()
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyObjectToEdit)
}
```

**In your View Model (or ViewBag) hold a variable denoting if this form should display readonly then read that value in the Razor view**

```
@if (Model.IsReadOnly)
{   
    <fieldset disabled="disabled">
        @FormContent()
    </fieldset>
}
else
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "HomeController"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @FormContent()

        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" />
    }
}
```

Setting a fieldset to disabled should disable all controls inside of it. You can also use CSS to remove any sort of fieldset formatting that you don't want.

You also get the benefit of not rendering an actual form tag or submit button at all since it's read only.